# Roslyn Analyzer, break build in vs2015

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Is it possible to get the analyzer error to break the build, I've the rule severity to error which does flag as a red squiggle in the IDE with an accompanying intellisense error. However if possible can you raise it as a build error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the analyzer to the compiler, instead of having it installed into VS as a VSIX in order for it to break the build.

Comment: Do you know know where I can find documentation or and example of this?

Comment: Referenced via Nuget and all was good, thank's for the help. Makes sense when I'd thought about it.